# PHP: Why should we use array_udiff()?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to understand array_udiff() function. 
But Its confusing that both functions array_diff() and array_udiff() produces same results then why will we use array_udiff() ?

**Code:**

```
 echo "<h1>array_udiff()</h1>";
 $a = array('a'=>'apple', 'c'=>'cat', 'b'=>'book');
 $b = array('d'=>'dog');
 echo "<pre>";

 print_r(array_udiff($a,$b,function($a,$b){
  if ($a < $b) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($a > $b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    };
 }));


 echo "<h1>array_diff()</h1>";

 print_r(array_diff($a, $b));
```

**Output:**

```
array_udiff()

Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => cat
    [c] => book
)


array_diff()

Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => cat
    [c] => book
)
```

As you can see in above example that output of both functions are same then why should we use `array_udiff()`?

Comment: You use very simple test data. Suppouse, you have array of objects or times in text forrmat

Comment: Yes but I need to understand that why should we use this? We can do the same task from the array_diff then why array_udiff?

Comment: When can, use array_diff . But as i've written, you can not always

Comment: Ok but in which cases? I need to understand simply that when will we need array_udiff

Comment: *Suppouse, you have array of objects or times in text forrmat*

Comment: Visit: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/11/php-arrayudiff.html

Comment: Thanks for response. Please tell me that why should I return -1, 0 and 1 ? What will this returned value impact on output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `array_udiff()` when the values in the arrays are not something that can be compared with `<`, `>` and `==` operators. Since PHP does not support operator overloading, arrays with objects need to be told how to be compared. For example, try using `array_diff()` on arrays with `Car` objects, but you want to compare them by their release year:

```
$result = array_udiff($a, $b, function($a, $b){
    return $b->getYear() - $a->getYear();
});
```

Using `array_diff()` wouldn't work since PHP doesn't know how to compare the objects. This goes for all PHP array functions that take a custom function for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for response.
Please tell me that why should I return -1, 0 and 1 ? What will this returned value impact on output?

Comment: It doesn't return -1, 0 and 1. It returns less than 0, 0, and greater than zero (which is what PHP wants). If car `$a` is made in 2012 and `$b` in 2010, then the function will return -2 (2010 - 2012). You can flip the arguments around if you want to change the sort direction. If years are equal, it returns zero (2012 - 2012 == 0). This is standard practice when comparing numbers.

Comment: ok why php will expect less than 0, 0 and greater than zero? What will happen if condition returns less than 0, 0 and greater than 0 ?

Comment: Looks like I misread your comment. You should return <0, 0 or >0 because PHP uses that to determine how the values compare. In case of a diff, it only cares about equal/not equal. But it matters when sorting - <0 means greater so it comes first, 0 means tied, and >0 means less than.

Comment: I were testing example in http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php#example-5461

I switched the > < signs in callback function but that did not change anything.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't matter in the case of `array_udiff()`. It only cares about elements being equal or not. You would notice a difference when using `usort()` for example.

Comment: Strange thing. Programming languages are supposed to be optimally written, without innecesary/useless options. This 'options overload' only confuses programmers when they try to use it :(

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `array_udiff` is for. Write a function that compares two objects the way you would like, then tell `array_udiff` to use that function. Something like this:

```
function compare_objects($obj_a, $obj_b) {
  return $obj_a->id - $obj_b->id;
}

$diff = array_udiff($first_array, $second_array, 'compare_objects');
```

Or, if you're using PHP >= 5.3 you can just use an anonymous function instead of declaring a function:

```
$diff = array_udiff($first_array, $second_array,
  function ($obj_a, $obj_b) {
    return $obj_a->id - $obj_b->id;
  }
);
```